# ¿Cómo extraer el nombre de las tablas en SQLITE3?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Necesito extraer los nombres de las tablas de una base de datos en SQLITE3 y pasarlos a un vector. Este vector de nombres me servirá para poder consultar  y realizar sentencias SQL en función de cada nombre que esté contenido en el vector, asignando la posición del vector a una variable fija.

```
A="Variable fija"
```

Ejemplo de la sentencia

```
SELECT Nombre FROM A WHERE sección="Cerámica"
```

Adjunto el código en el que he trabajado pero que no he podido lograr el objetivo.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

```
import sqlite3 as sqlite

class Gen_info():
    db_name='Database.db'

    def __init__(self):
        self.view_table_log()
            

    def run_query(self,query,parameters=()):
        with sqlite.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
            cursor=conn.cursor()
            result=cursor.execute(query,parameters)
            conn.commit()
            print(result)
        return result

    def view_table_log(self):
        query='SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = "table" ORDER BY name'
        self.run_query(query)
```

Answer (score 2):

Quiero publicar la forma en la cual logré obtener el resultado esperado "Poder leer los nombres de las tablas contenidas en un archivo .DB de sqlite3"

```
import sqlite3 as sqlite
import os

class Gen_info:
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        folder=os.getcwd()
        db_folder=(folder+os.sep+"Data_Bases"+os.sep)
        self.db_name=(db_folder+'database.db')
        print(self.db_name)
def run_query(self,query,parameters=()):
        with sqlite.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
            self.cursor=conn.cursor()
            self.result=self.cursor.execute(query,parameters)
            conn.commit()
        return self.result

    def view_table_log(self):
        query='SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table" ORDER BY name'
        self.run_query(query)
        array=[item[0]for item in self.cursor.fetchall()]
        return array
```

Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Por favor, proporciona detalles adicionales en tu respuesta. Tal como está escrita actualmente, es difícil entender tu solución.

Comment: De cuerdo con tu solicitud expongo que el código mostrado hace parte de una extensión que uso para un script que genera un GUI. Lo primero que se hace es buscar el nombre de la carpeta donde está alojado el archivo .DB y asignar a la variable self.db_name la ruta dentro del sistema operativo, posterior a esto se crea una función de consulta genérica a la cual se le pasa la consulta SQL contenida en el método  def view_table_log(self):. Al final se normaliza la información obtenida por le método Fetchall() y se obtiene la lista de nombres de la tablas contenidas dentro de un archivo .DB